# How do I get my invisible Textboxes to get visible if I click a radio button?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I wrote an asp C# WebApplication.

I need to "fade" in asp textboxes if I click a certain radio button. (They need to fade in as soon as I click the radio button). How can I do that?. Should I use JS for this?

Comment: what you are already trying

Comment: `$(RADIO).on('change', function(){ $(':input:hidden').toggle(this.checked); })`

Comment: What does your textboxes look like in asp.net?

Comment: Example of a textbox: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxStrasse"></asp:TextBox><asp:Label ID="LabelStrasseError" class="labels" runat="server" Text="Bitte ausfüllen" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red"> @Arg0n

Comment: How is it hidden? With CSS?

Comment: yes exactly @Arg0n

Comment: Could you please post you HTML including the checkbox and the textboxes, and also your CSS. So we can help you. In the question.

Comment: `<asp:TextBox...` is very much not asp-classic. Why did you add that tag? What part of this is actually asp-classic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to create "behavior" and CSS to add styles and effects.

Here an example using simple JavaScript, with no requirement for jQuery or other libraries. The script assume you are hiding your element using a combination of `visibility` and `opacity`.

It works in this way:

- Listen to event `change` on your radio button.
- When user select radio button.
- Select radio button and add class `fadeout`.
- CSS class `fadeout` contains a transition which create your animation effect.

> CSS transitions, provide a way to control animation speed when
>   changing CSS properties. Instead of having property changes take
>   effect immediately, you can cause the changes in a property to take
>   place over a period of time. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

```js
var txtBox = document.getElementById('txtBox');
var radioMale = document.getElementById('radioMale');
radioMale.addEventListener('change', function() {
  txtBox.classList.add('fadeout');
}.bind(this));
```

```css
.fadeout {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="radioMale"> Male
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtBox">
<br>
```

---

Here an example for the reverse, where you can "fade in" with an animation your text box when an user select a radio button.

```js
var txtBox = document.getElementById('txtBox');
var radioMale = document.getElementById('radioMale');
radioMale.addEventListener('change', function() {
  txtBox.classList.add('fadein');
}.bind(this));
```

```css
.fadeout {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadein {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 100;
  transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="radioMale"> Male
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtBox" class="fadeout">
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

1) your **HTML**

```
<p>Show textboxes
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r1" value="Show">Do nothing
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r2" value="Nothing">
</p>Wonderful textboxes:
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #1
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #2
        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
```

2) **Js** code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#r1").click(function () {
        $(".text").fadeIn();
    });
    $("#r2").click(function () {
        $(".text").fadeOut();
    });
});
```